# SSL и не SSL на Apache

Tags: apache, ssl

У меня есть два VirtualHost на одном Apache, один 000-default.conf и один site.conf.
На site.conf включен SSL и подключен сертификат.
Если из браузера обращаться по https://site.com, то открывается хост site.com, если по http, то аналогично, там стоит редирект на https.
Если обращаться http://ip, то открывается 000-default, но если по https://ip, то открывается site.com с предупреждением о небезопасном соединении, поскольку сертификат привязан к IP.
Как сделать чтобы при обращении к https://ip открывался 000-default или шел редирект на http?

Конфиги:

000-default:

```
<VirtualHost ip.ip.ip.ip:80>

    ServerName ip.ip.ip.ip
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

site.com:

```
<VirtualHost site.com:443>
    ServerName site.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/site/www

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/ssl_certs/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/ssl_certs/key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/ssl_certs/chainfile.crt

    ErrorLog /home/site/error.log
    CustomLog /home/site/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/site/www>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId user group
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost site.com:80>
    ServerName site.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Никак. HTTPS никогда не будет открываться без корректного сертификата, а сертификатов для IP никто не выдаёт и вряд ли станет выдавать

Comment: То есть нельзя даже редирект сделать?

Comment: Нельзя, редиректы это тоже часть HTTP(S)

Answer (score 0):

файл по этому и называется 000-***
т.к. апач берёт их в алфавитном порядке.
если ты обращаешься по адресу, то и переход идёт туда, что в первом по алфавиту файле написано.
только вот это `ServerName ip.ip.ip.ip` там не нужно `ip.ip.ip.ip` он и так откроется если ты по адресу зайдёшь.
ну и поскольку сертификаты делаются для имён comonName- параметр при генерации ключа, то при переходе по адресу всегда будет ошибка сертификата, а все редиректы срабатывают позже.
если ты пойдёшь по `http://ip` (а не `https://ip`), то редирект можно сделать и он сработает.

000-default:

```
<VirtualHost ip.ip.ip.ip:80>
   ServerName site.com
   ServerAlias www.site.com
   Redirect / https://site.com/
</VirtualHost>
...
```